# Accessibility implementation for Google Maps Marker in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, accessibility, google-maps-markers

I have to announce some customised content for my marker in google maps without showing the infoWindow for it. This is a part of accessibility implementation for a project.

Currently, I set the title(which needs to be announced) and have tried using setOnMarkClickListener. I call the hideInfoWindow function inside it. The problem with this approach is that when I click on the marker, it announces my content along with "Double Tap to Activate"(something related to accessibility).I need to avoid the extra text as a part of the requirement. (which basically would mean to make the marker not clickable)

I have also checked setContentDescription but it announces content for the whole map.

I want to basically make the marker non-interactable, not show the infoWindow but announce some text on accessibilty.

Is there a way to hide the infoWindow without a click listener and announce only the exact content I want?

Comment: This one seems to be a good request. Could you please file a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188870&template=788712)? Thanks!